# Javascript DOM encoded html code problem

Tags: javascript, dom

```
    var accordion = document.createTextNode(tp.getAccordionContent());
    var el = document.createElement("div");
    el.appendChild(accordion);
    document.getElementById("gp").appendChild(el);
```

tp.getAccordion() function returns me a string like < div .... and it is being decoded. All I want is to get it encoded and implement the div which has an id = gp with that data.

any help and advises would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("gp").innerHTML = tp.getAccordionContent();
```

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementById("gp").innerHTML += "..."; might be what you want